# Observer for controller's action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to recording some action, like user open some view, click some link.  But I do not want to use google analytics because some action is called by remote mobile client.  Any plugin or gem can do that like observer for Active:Record?  I also show these action with graph.

Answer (score 0):

Try mixpanel. Highly recommend it.

Comment: looks nice but the data will send to outside. I want to keep tracking data in local database.